# Pandas UDF that operates on arrays

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark UDF that takes an array and returns its suffix:

```
func.udf( lambda ng: ng[1:], ArrayType(IntegerType()) )
```

Is it possible to turn it into a scalar pandas_udf? 
Does Pandas offer the necessary vectorized operations?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get the same functionality with scalar pandas udf but make sure that you return a Series with list of lists from the udf as the series normally expects a list of elements and your row array is flattened and converted to multiple rows if you return directly the list as series.

**Edited** As pointed out by OP in comments my previous answer(pd.Series([v[0][1:]]) using index is wrong and works only in certain conditions. Now corrected.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([([1,2,3],'val1'),([4,5,6],'val2')],['col1','col2'])
df.show()
+---------+----+
| col1|col2|
+---------+----+
|[1, 2, 3]|val1|
|[4, 5, 6]|val2|
+---------+----+

from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf,PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pandas as pd

@pandas_udf(ArrayType(LongType()))
def func(v):
    res=[]
    for row in v:
        res.append(row[1:])
    return pd.Series(res)

df.withColumn('col3',func(df.col1)).show()
+---------+----+------+
|col1     |col2|col3  |
+---------+----+------+
|[1, 2, 3]|val1|[2, 3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|val2|[5, 6]|
+---------+----+------+
```

The other way is to use apply similar to what you have done:

```
@pandas_udf(ArrayType(LongType()))
def func(v):
    return v.apply(lambda x:x[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.
1. From which of the two solutions would you expect the largest speed benefit?
2. What is the meaning of "[0]" in v[0][1:] ?
3. I've noticed that your first solution tends to work only for Spark Dataframes created from scratch. In other cases, half the time we get: 
        RuntimeError: Result vector from pandas_udf was not the required length: expected XXX, got 1
I gather this has to do with partitioning, because even in your example, if you modify it to be: df.repartition(3).withColumn('col3',func(df.col1)).show() you'll get the same error.
Ideas? Thanks

Comment: @GoErlangen thanks for the query and pointing out my mistake.
1.The pandas apply method should be much faster.
2 & 3 are actually related.
2.When applying pandas udf to the column it is taking the column as a series. So I am accessing the first row of the series. So my answer returns only the first row.
3. Yes it is due to partitioning and depending on the number of executors, a single executor may get either 1 row or all 2 rows together in my example. 
That causes the error because when an executor gets all 2 rows I return only the first row in the method. I will edit the answer.

Comment: if it pass numpy array to pd.Series then it fails. Key was to use plain python array